Google Script appendRow() not working when entire sheet is filtered
I found a problem using appendRow method of google scripts when the entire sheet has filters enabled.
I'm trying to append 3 new rows in the sheet below, via google apps scripts:



Date
Code
Name
Status




30/04/2024 13:16:50
DSPACE
TEST 1
OK


01/05/2024 12:02:02
DSPACE
TEST 2
OK


01/05/2024 12:12:55
DSPACE
TEST 3
NOK



The steps to replicate the problem are:

Enable  a sheet with the filter enabled in all columns, not only where there's data, like in this image :
.

Filter the column code only with "DSPACE". Note that with all columns filtered, appeared a "Blank spaces" option in the filter;


Now, run the code below:
function myFunction() {
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetUrl);
    
    Logger.log(sheet.getLastRow()); // in this case, returns 4

    sheet.appendRow([new Date(), 'DSPACE', 'TEST 4']);
    sheet.appendRow([new Date(), 'DSPACE', 'TEST 5']);
    sheet.appendRow([new Date(), 'DSPACE', 'TEST 6']);
    
    Logger.log(sheet.getLastRow()); // with 'DSPACE' filter, returns 4, else, returns 7
}

If the range is not filtered, filtered with "Blank spaces" or the filter is available only to the correct columns, the rows are appended correctly.

Otherwise, the data simply vanish, with no errors, and no row is appended.
Am I missing something?

Unfortunately your [mcve] does not reproduce the problem so we can't really help you.

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Following your image link would require me to expose my email to you and I wont do that

Thank you for the guidelines, updated the question. @cooper, would you please try to reproduce the problem again? The problem occurs 'cause the users of the sheet click on the rectangle in the top-left corner, and then, click on the filter icon.

I never use those filters.  I prefer to use code.

Issue and workaround:
I confirmed the same situation with you before. Ref When the values are put with appendRow() to the sheet reflected by the basic filter, it seems that the rows are not appended. This might be still the current specification. This has already been mentioned in my post In that post, I used a workaround to put the values using setValues and refresh the basic filter. When setValues is used, the values can be put even when the sheet has the basic filter.
But, here, I noticed a new issue. In the case of the values including the date object, when the values including the date object are put to the sheet reflected by the basic filter using setValues, the date objects cannot be put. This might be the new issue. So, in this answer, I would like to propose the following flow.

Copy the current basic filter.
Remove the current basic filter.
Append the values including the date objects to the sheet.
Set the basic filter from the copied basic filter.

By this flow, the values including the date objects can be appended to the sheet reflecting the basic filter. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.
Modified script:
Please set your Spreadsheet ID and sheet name.
function myFunction() {
  const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // Copy the current basic filter and remove it.
  const filter = sheet.getFilter();
  const obj = { filterCriteria: [] };
  if (filter) {
    obj.filterRange = filter.getRange();
    for (var i = obj.filterRange.getColumn(), maxCol = obj.filterRange.getLastColumn(); i <= maxCol; i++) {
      var filterCriterion = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(i);
      if (filterCriterion) {
        obj.filterCriteria.push([i, filterCriterion]);
      }
    }
    filter.remove();
  }

  Logger.log(sheet.getLastRow());

  // Append values.
  const now = new Date();
  const values = [
    [now, 'DSPACE', 'TEST 4'],
    [now, 'DSPACE', 'TEST 5'],
    [now, 'DSPACE', 'TEST 6'],
  ];
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);

  // I think that in this method, the following 3 lines can be also worked. But, from the process cost, I put the values using setValues.
  // sheet.appendRow([new Date(), 'DSPACE', 'TEST 4']);
  // sheet.appendRow([new Date(), 'DSPACE', 'TEST 5']);
  // sheet.appendRow([new Date(), 'DSPACE', 'TEST 6']);

  Logger.log(sheet.getLastRow());

  // Paste the coped basic filter.
  if (obj.filterCriteria.length > 0) {
    const filter = obj.filterRange.createFilter();
    obj.filterCriteria.forEach(([i, filterCriterion]) => filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(i, filterCriterion));
  }
}

Testing:
When this script is run using your showing table, the following result is obtained.

Note:

This is a simple sample script for using your provided table. When your actual situation is more complicated from this situation, this script might not be able to be used. At that time, please modify the script. My proposed script is tested for your showing table and basic filter in your question. Please be careful about this.

References:

Related thread.

Bug with Woocommerce Webhook and Google Sheet API?


setValues(values)

